# Swift TableView reload data when push back button on navigation controller

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

i have a problem. I have a tableview in the ViewController1, if i click that it goes to ViewController2 where i can change a variable; when i push back button on the navigation controller to go back in the ViewController1 i should see the variable i changed in the DetailLabel. My problem is that i need to reload the data of the TableView but i can't do it! I already tried to put `TableView.reloaddata()` in the ViewDidLoad, but nothing happened! How can i do this?

thanks in advance

Comment: Call `reloadData` in the `viewWillAppear:` method, not `viewDidLoad`.